# What are the pro's and con's of keeping web content as html when showing it in Android/iOS client apps?

Tags: android, html, ios, user-interface, user-experience

I am designing a Web app that has lots of 'blog' like content (articles, reviews, comments etc).

In addition to users reading content via web browsers on desktops etc, I am writing a Android (and later iOS) mobile app that users can view and interact with the content via Restful api.

**My question is: should I maintain and display the content as HTML format in mobile app (simply showing the content in a webview widget) or is it better practise to parse the html into a separate native widgets on Android/iOS?**

For example, maybe my html has a group of paragraphs with a few pictures; which on Android would turn into a series of native TextViews and some ImageViews.

Obviously the webview html way is simpler to implement, but will give a non mobile UI experience.

**Bonus information: Feedback on peoples experience and suggestions approaching this in past would be most helpful.**

**UPDATE After some feedback: Seems most people are going for the webview approach for simplicity reasons. Having looked at a few mobile apps, it seems they do this. Has anyone seen mobile apps that do the native content approach?**

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't have enough reputation to add a comment I am writing here as an idea.As you want to develop it in also IOS platform i think you can use phoneGap.It will give you better options as well as less work as you have already the web solutions. You can handle users interactions using javascript in phoneGap.

Comment: this is not what the question is about, i.e how to do a mobile app, rather it is about a choice of approach between displaying content as html or via native rendering

Comment: Yeah, sorry @riaz hasan, nikos m is correct, I'm looking for more about the pros and cons regarding the UI and UX.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to not include the information directly in the web page but load it from an REST interface or something similar. On the web page you can do this using JavaScript. In the native apps you can load the information and build a custom view. Parsing the data from a HTML string is bad practice, as changes on your web page might affect your apps. Also there is a little amount of computing time needed to parse the data (although this might be a negligible factor) and a lot of code.

Comment: yes, I was always going to use a restful api that delivered the 'article' based on DB field content - instead of direct web page scraping ;-(. But it is tempting to store the  content (article text and images) as html in the db, for formatting gains

Comment: i do agree that using html data on the mobile app 'feels' wrong though!

Comment: If you only want to use HTML for the article itself and not for the meta data (I thought you wanted to load your entire page and parse the data from it) HTML is perfectly fine. You can add CSS code to yout WebView to style the HTML as you wish and generated a nice and integrated look and feel. You can also think about writing your articles in something like markdown.

Comment: yes and by using a local css stylesheet, I gain the ability to show content offline (assuming I persist the content returned by rest call).

Comment: Exactely. You can use a library like volley for caching. By using local CSS you can minimize the transmitted data (users with a tight cellular data contract will thank you)

Comment: I am wondering if a half way house of maybe storing data in markdown would help. The markdown on web page would turn into html, and native images/textviews in native app. More work of cause. Has anyone been down this route?

Comment: This would be a lot of work as you would need a custom model to store the information and some code building the view from the model. Using just an WebView will be no visible difference for the user but less work for you. By styling the WebView you wll see no difference.

Comment: if i went with the parsing approach on android, I would gain from the flexibility of content being separate. Thus allowing showing content differently on mobile - e.g. I could show the images as a separate slideshow in android ui (e.g. 'article featured image').

Comment: @DEzra, maybe using json data from your rest web service is best and then render those data either as html content (e.g via a template engine) or natively. This way your data service remains the same and the rendering can change as need in the mobile app